# Python TLS. Можно ли извлечь публичный ключ из сертификата для шифрования данных им?

Tags: python, шифрование, tls

Создал самоподписанный сертификат+приватный ключ к нему для TLS соединений по сокетам.

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:3072 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout cerver.key -out server.crt
```

Но внутри TLS оболочки хотел дополнительно шифровать весь трафик сессионным симметричным ключом. По следующему алгоритму:

1. Клиент посылает на сервер публ. ключ.
2. Сервер генерирует сессионный симметричный ключ и шифрует его публичным ключом клиента. После чего отправляет клиенту.
3. Клиент дешифрует полученный сим. ключ своим закрытым.
4. Шифруем и дешифруем используя сим. ключ.

Но нужно решить: пару ключей откр.-закр. можно сессионно генерировать (но это сравнительно долго), или использовать открытый-закрытый ключ от сертификата. Если закр. ключ от сертификата лежит в отдельном файле, то открытый - внутри сертификата, но я не нашел способа его оттуда извлечь, хотя мне казалось, что это очень простая операция.

Вопрос:
Как извлечь публичный ключ из сертификата? Пишу код на Python, но многие команды по типу генерации и извлечения ключей отправляю в командную строку к openssl (не хватает знаний). Комментарии непосредственно по идее приветствуются.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: Спасибо! Прошу прощения за беспокойство, но не вполне понимаю о чем вы. Немного изменил формулировки, надеюсь, это исправило мой вопрос.

Comment: Вот посмотрите, в вопросе он извлекает публичный ключ из сертификата. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72963934/how-to-get-the-private-key-from-the-cert-file

Comment: @СергейКох Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Записываете сертификат в буфер.
2. Функцией [`OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate`](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate) парсите сертификат. На выходе получаете объект типа [`OpenSSL.crypto.X509`](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.X509)
3. У объектов `X509` есть метод [`get_pubkey`](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_pubkey). Возвращает объект типа [`OpenSSL.crypto.PKey`](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.PKey)
4. Объект `PKey` напрямую непригоден для шифрования. Сначала его нужно превратить в криптографический ключ методом [`to_cryptography_key`](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.PKey.to_cryptography_key). Результат - объект типа [`cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicKey`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicKey)
5. У объекта `RSAPublicKey` есть метод [`encrypt`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicKey.encrypt)

Вот пример скрипта, который шифрует строку `Hello, World!` и сохраняет шифртекст в файл `encrypted.bin`:

```
import string
import OpenSSL.crypto as openssl
import cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa as rsa
import cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.padding as padding

f = open('server.crt','r')
certBuf = f.read()
f.close()

cert = openssl.load_certificate(openssl.FILETYPE_PEM, certBuf)
pkey = cert.get_pubkey()

assert pkey.type() == openssl.TYPE_RSA, "Not an RSA certificate"

cryptokey = pkey.to_cryptography_key()
assert isinstance(cryptokey, rsa.RSAPublicKey), "Not an RSA key"

plaintext = "Hello, World!".encode("utf-8")
ciphertext = cryptokey.encrypt(plaintext, padding.PKCS1v15())

hexstring = "".join(["{:02x}".format(b) for b in ciphertext])
print(hexstring)

out = open("encrypted.bin", 'wb')
out.truncate()
out.write(ciphertext)
out.close()
```

Проверка правильности шифрования:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -in encrypted.bin -inkey cerver.key
```

Вывод команды:

```
Hello, World!
```

Что и требовалось получить.